# Is there a way to create an array of all attributes from a website's HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, attributes

I'd like to create a program that will allow me to input a hyperlink address and the output would display a list of attribute contents. For example, inputting a Netflix genre hyperlink for [Adventure Movies](https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7442) and receiving a list output for all the movie titles and individual movie title links for that genre.

I looked at the View Page Source data for this genre and saw this code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","name":"Adventure Movies","itemListElement":
[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"@type":"Movie","name":"The Adam Project","url":"https://www.netflix.com/title/81309354"}},
{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"@type":"Movie","name":"Red Notice","url":"https://www.netflix.com/title/81161626"}}
```

I'm thinking that there's a way to retrieve the "name" and "url" attributes for each item in the list and display them in an array?

Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with programming beyond some basic HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I'm not sure what programming language would be needed to do this. It seems like the script is in JSON - would I use JSON to do this?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I could do it in watir. Not for free though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is really just a common notation for organizing data. It's not a language in itself. Lots of sites use this notation for sending/receiving data. It works well with Javascript as well as many other programing languages.

Effectively, what you are trying to do is scrape data from netflix. How exactly you go about this might depend on your ultimate goals, and what technologies you're willing to learn.

While javascript can certainly manipulate json info very easily, I believe you'll run into security issues trying to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the contents of https://www.netflix.com/browse/genre/7442 from a javascript file running outside of the netflix domain.

Javascript and fetch are often used to grab external data where permission is given. Ideally from an api endpoint returning json rather than an html file. Unfortunately netflix no longer offers a public API. I don't know much about them, or what strings are attached, but it appears there are 3rd parties offering an api for netflix data...

You need to look into [the legality of it](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/o1gxw1/how_to_get_info_on_which_movies_are_on_netflix/), but you could also look at learning web scraping tools like:

- Scrapy (Python) - https://scrapy.org/
- Beautiful soup (Python) - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/
- Selenium (supported by many languages including JS with node) - https://www.selenium.dev/ - This one is a more general browser automation tool and less specific to scraping.